# How to buffer audio from url using axios in modern javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to buffer audio from url using axios in modern js **not jQuery**

```js
var url = 'https://my_image.jpg' // example
url = axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
return Buffer.from(url.data);
```

**The above code buffers image, In order to buffer audio like that, What should I do?**

I used `responseType: 'blob'` to buffer audio from url but it couldn't be played, its 0 seconds. But in url its 7 seconds.

```js
var url = 'https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=Hello%20Everyone!%20How%20are%20you?&tl=en&total=1&idx=0&textlen=5&client=tw-ob&prev=input&ttsspeed=1'
```

**I wanna buffer the audio url in the above variable using axios in modern js.**

**Also i need help in making a global regex for '\n'. I wanna replace all '\n' with space ( ' ' )**

Comment: Please antone help me its urgent 

Comment: how are you playing buffered audio? are you using Audio tag?

Comment: the request returns promise? are you considering it?

Comment: check this out if it helps
_audio array buffer example_: https://mdn.github.io/fetch-examples/fetch-array-buffer/  
_mdn_: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/arrayBuffer